# Rails: find all resources not already connected through join table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I am trying to rewrite actions which connect and disconnect products to and from projects. Currently my `select_to_project` view shows all products, but I would like it to display only products which have not been already connected to a given project.

Products and projects are connected through a join table

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects, :join_table => "projects_products"  
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products, :join_table => "projects_products" 
end

class ProjectsProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :project_id, :product_id

  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :product
end
```

In my products controller I currently have:

```
def select_to_project
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  @products = Product.find(:all)
end

def select_from_project
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])
end
```

Obviously the `select_to_project` view currently displays all possible products, even those which are already connected through the join table.

I thought the `select_to_project` action should be changed to something like this:

```
def select_to_project
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  @products = Product.joins(:projects => :products).where('products_projects_join.product_id IS NOT ?', @product)
end
```

But I currently get an MySQL error when I try to load the relative view:

```
Mysql::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1)' at line 1: SELECT `products`.* FROM `products` INNER JOIN `projects_products` ON `projects_products`.`product_id` = `products`.`id` INNER JOIN `projects` ON `projects`.`id` = `projects_products`.`project_id` INNER JOIN `projects_products` `products_projects_join` ON `products_projects_join`.`project_id` = `projects`.`id` INNER JOIN `products` `products_projects` ON `products_projects`.`id` = `products_projects_join`.`product_id` WHERE (products_projects_join.project_id IS NOT 1)
```

How can I get this query working in Rails 3?

Thank you very much in advance.

**Update**

Thanks to @Sebastian Palma the view now builds, but the query result is not correct.

```
@products = Product.joins(:projects => :products).where('products_projects_join.project_id != ?', @project.id).uniq.order(:id, :order => 'id ASC')
```

Which produces the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 'products'.* FROM 'products' INNER JOIN 'projects_products' ON 'projects_products'.'product_id' = 'products'.'id' INNER JOIN 'projects' ON 'projects'.'id' = 'projects_products'.'project_id' INNER JOIN 'projects_products' 'products_projects_join' ON 'products_projects_join'.'project_id' = 'projects'.'id' INNER JOIN 'products' 'products_projects' ON 'products_projects'.'id' = 'products_projects_join'.'product_id' WHERE (products_projects_join.project_id != 2) ORDER BY id, '--- \n:order: id ASC\n'
```

I have 14 product entries and project 2 is already connected to 4 of them.

```
projects_products_id / project_id / product_id
3 2 1
4 2 2
5 2 3
6 2 12
```

My query should display products with the ids: 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14.

It currently displays products 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13.

Product 14 is not currently present on the join table, 3 and 12 are already connected and 11 is not connected.

It is as if the query results slid one id value to the left.

Ideally I would like to find all entries from the products table which are not already connected on the join table to a given project.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `IS NOT`? Try `where('products_projects_join.product_id != ?', @product.id)`.

Comment: @SebastianPalma thanks I always thought `IS NOT` == `!=`. Now, with `@products = Product.joins(:projects => :products).where('products_projects_join.project_id != ?', @project.id).uniq.order(:id, :order => 'id ASC')
` the view renders, but the query result is not right. I will add some more info to my question.

Comment: @SebastianPalma I added some data. It appears that the results are always id-1. Just like when products[0] is the first entry. Do you know why this happens? How can I get this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have setup the association as `has_and_belongs_to_many` but has HABTM is headless so it makes no sense to actually have a join model as well.

Instead you want to setup the assocation as `has_many through:` and use a conventional name for the table.

Start by renaming the join table to `project_products` and make sure it has an id column.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :project_products 
  has_many :projects, through: project_products 
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :project_products 
  has_many :products, through: project_products 
end

class ProjectProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :project_id, :product_id
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :product
end
```

This will let you join through the association `project_products`.

The easiest way to do this is by performing a subquery. In modern versions of Rails you would do:

```
Product.where.not(
  id: project.products
)
```

Which creates the follow query:

```
SELECT "products".* FROM "products" 
WHERE "products"."id" NOT IN (
  SELECT "products"."id" FROM "products" 
  INNER JOIN "project_products" ON "products"."id" = "project_products"."product_id" 
  WHERE "project_products"."project_id" = $1
) LIMIT $2
```

However `where.not` was introduced in Rails 4.0. As a workaround you can use a string in Rails 3.

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :project_products
  has_many :projects, through: :project_products

  def self.not_assigned_to_project(project)
    Product.where("
      products.id NOT IN (#{project.products.select(:id).to_sql})
    ")
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't have Rails 3 installed so this code was just tested in Rails 6. Your milage may vary.

Comment: thanks a lot. I suspect I have to use `@products = Product.not_assigned_to_project(@project)` in my controller? With your input I get: `Mysql::Error: Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous: SELECT 'products'.* FROM 'products'  WHERE (products.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM 'products' INNER JOIN 'project_products' ON 'products'.'id' = 'project_products'.'product_id' WHERE 'project_products'.'project_id' = 2))`

Comment: Yes. Try `project.products.select('products.id').to_sql`.

Comment: YESSSS + dancing! Thank you VERY MUCH! I always used a join table the way I do and I can get entries which are connected, but as of today was unable to get entries which are not connected.

Comment: I always used HABTM + join table `projects_products` + relative model `projects_product.rb` which should be almost identical to a has_many through, or? Thanks again + more dancing ;0)

Comment: The difference between HABTM and `has_many through:` is that the later uses a model to join through plus that HABTM uses a stupid table naming scheme that goes against every other convention in rails. HABTM is actually pretty useless since you can't query the join table or add any additional data to the join table. https://flatironschool.com/blog/why-you-dont-need-has-and-belongs-to-many

Comment: The way you have set it up just seems silly. You have all the cons of both approaches and none of the advantages of `has_many through:`.

Comment: If I may ask a follow up: How would one declare an alias in a has_many through? When `authors > project_curators > projects` and project.rb : `has_many :curators, :class_name => :author, :through => :project_curators`? In a HABTM I could set `has_and_belongs_to_many : curators, :class_name => :author, :join_table => "projects_ curators"`... but here I get: `uninitialized constant Project::author`

Comment: The class name option needs to be the actual name of the class 'Author'. But it would be better if you asked a new question.